# The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`', but this dictionary requires a model item of type

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I need to fetch one record from database on a certain id in asp.net mvc using ado.net to connect with the database  but its keep on giving errors.

```
 public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        var result=_context.Funds.Where(move => move.Id == id)
          .Take(1).ToList();
        if (result == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(result);
    }
```

@model Echosystem.Models.FdxViewModel

and if I change this to @model List<Echosystem.Models.FdxViewModel> it gives the CS1061 error of missing a directive or model doesn't contains definition for the field
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GWdP.png)

Comment: you need to change the model in your `details.cshtml` page it should be exactly of type you are passing in your controller action. Look for `@Model` directive on top of view page. [ref: link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-6.0#model)
you are passing the `List<Funds>` while the error shows `List<FdxViewModel>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Take(1)" still yields a list of objects  even if it is a list with only 1 element. Change it to "First" and omit "ToList". That will give you a single object.